Unity How to test Steam remote play together?
I built a small game prototype because I wanted to test steam remote play together.
I installed Steamworkts.net and I can confirm that it works when I press play in the Unity editor.
The issue comes when I invite someone to play. The invited person can see my screen, but not make any inputs. Obviously I allowed that person to controll with mouse and keyboard but in their screen there is just an empty message.
First this screen is shown:

Then this is displayed in the middle of the screen, the other person can still see my desktop and everything... just cant do anything:

Im questioning if this is even possible at all, streaming the unity editor window to playtest. Because if this was a steam published game it would work, but the fee is 100$ and makes no sense to pay that for my testing purposes
If I try to make a build and add it to steam as a "non steam game" it doesnt show me the option to invite people for remote play. Since its a non steam game, makes sense.
How can I test this without paying the 100$ fee required to launch a product on steam?
Thank you!
